# Regular expression to get content between 2 tags in a multiline string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regex in Java to extract contents out of a multiline string that is between 2 tags. For example, the content may look like this:

```
--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

hello test

...

..
!@#!@%$#^%$&*^(*)*()
..
..
..



..


--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

hello test<br><br>..<br>!@#!@%$#^%$&*^(*)*()<br>.<br><br>.<br>.<br>.<br><br><br><br>.<br><br>

--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_
```

I want to extract just the contents between the `--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_` boundaries.

I used a regular expression that looks like this: `--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_\n?[.\n]+\n?--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_`

But it doesn't work. What should my regular expression be to extract the content? Also, when extracting, would the boundary tags be included together with the content?

Comment: How do you want to handle that there are more than 2 occurrences of the tag in the text? Get all information between the first and the last one? Get one group result for each content in between each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend not to use regular expressions for parsing. They are not well suited for that. Just write a parser that iterates over your input, searches for the start tag, sets a flag, records all following lines, recognizes the end tag and resets the flag. Easily done and much more flexible than regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_).*(?=--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_)
```

This awfully looking regex can be used to extract your content without boundaries. However this will **only** work if there are no nested "tags" in your input. Also not that to make it work `.` must match the newline character.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<=--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_).*(?=--_000_CAKETFEgg78oKKJPNySnxF4BgQoh9ifHP4XzXGeJddUvOtz5wmailgm_)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not that big, say, you could read it once into memory. you can extract things with regex.

However if the file is a huge file, you will have problem, even if you can read it into memory, processing with regex on that would not be fast.

In this case, reading the file line by line or as stream would be generic way to solve the problem. you can searching and extracting the content by reading. It wouldn't be harder to implement than regex.